Isomorphism locus of a morphism of objects in the derived category is Zariski open?
Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring and $\text{Mod} R$ be the category of $R$-modules. Let $M,N\in \mathcal D(\text{Mod } R)$ with finitely generated homologies. Let $f: M\to N$ be a morphism in $\mathcal D(\text{Mod } R)$.  Is the set $$\{\mathfrak p\in \text{Spec}(R)\mid f_{\mathfrak p}\text{ is an isomorphism in } \mathcal D(\text{Mod } R_{\mathfrak p})\}$$ a Zariski open subset of $\text{Spec}(R)$ ?

Usually, loci of isomorphisms are usually open, not closed. Is this a typo?

@Ben: you're right ... my bad :( fixed it now

Oh, and have you tried comparing this set with the complement of the support of the mapping cone of $f$?

@Ben: agh, so like it $f_{\mathfrak p}$ is an isomorphism in $\mathcal D(R_{\mathfrak  p})$ if and only if $Cone(f_{\mathfrak  p}) \simeq Cone(f){\mathfrak p}\simeq 0$ in $\mathcal  D(R{\mathfrak p})$ ?

The details would have to be checked, but that was essentially the idea, @Alex

@Ben: thanks... is it not known that a morphism in the derived category is an isomorphism if and only if its mapping cone is 0
and mapping cone commutes with localization ?

For some reason, I was not entirely sure how obvious commutation of the mapping cone with localisation was, but I have just realised that it's  indeed obvious from the construction. (I thought the universal property should have to be checked and was too lazy to think about it any further.)

@Ben: right, for complexes, we have a hands on construction (not sure what would happen for more abstract localization in general triangulated categories though...)
